# Permisões de chave de registro Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows, object-pascal

As configurações de segurança do Windows muitas vezes não permitem que as chaves de registro sejam alteradas pelo usuário. Como é o caso da chave: **"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\ CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree"** que gerencia os arquivos do software responsável por agendar tarefas no sistema, as permissões desta chave podem ser facilmente alteradas através do Regedit, seria possível alterar estas mesmas permissões de edição da chave através do Delphi?

Comment: Qual sua intenção com isso?

Comment: Validar meu projeto na feira de ciências FEBRACE

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível mas não é tão simples, e é necessário que o usuário executando a aplicação possua permissões para tanto. As permissões necessárias podem variar com a chave que se deseja alterar, podendo ser necessário até possuir permissão de administrador.

Verifique a documentação do MSDN específica para tanto. O procedimento em sí não é simples e varia muito com o que efetivamente deseja obter.

Segue link para a documentação:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878(v=vs.85).aspx

Pode ser que na unidade `Windows` as funções necessárias não estão se quer declaradas, sendo necessário que você manualmente faça a declaração dos externals das funções que irá utilizar.

Comment: Como posso implementar isto no Delphi ou Lazarus?